# How to set conditions in a Haskell List Comprehension

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, list-comprehension, modulo

Im trying to generate a list of all Numbers bigger than *0* with the following conditions:

- all elements are odd
- all elements divide trough 7 without remainder
- all elements divide trough 9 with remainder 3

e.g. `[21,147,273,399,...]`

I tried : `[x | x <- [1..] , odd x, x / 2 == 0, ...` (and here I had  problems)

Comment: Have you looked up a tutorial? This is likely covered in *any* comprehension tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no clear effort or attempt.  StackOverflow is best seen as help with clear-cut bugs and not a from scratch code-writing service or substitute for a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry Thomas. I already tried to give my previous attempt, but the system gaved message : "this post does not meet our quality standart".

Comment: if you didn't know about the existence of `mod`, you could've coded it yourself with a list comprehension too! `mod n d == 0` === `last [n, n-d..0] == ??` so `[x | x <- [1..] , odd x, x % 2 == 0]` === `[x | x <- [1..] , odd x, last [n, n-d..0]==??]` === `[x | x <- [1..] , odd x, y <- [n, n-d..0], y==??]`.

Comment: Here I had problems. Not exactly a helpful problem description. Read about [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

just to get you started a partial answer

```
[x | x <- [1..], odd x, mod x 7==?, ??? ]

[21,147,273,399,525,651,777,903,1029,1155...]
```

it can't get simpler than this, just translate your verbal description to code, exactly one to one...

Comment: hi Karakfa, Thank you for the advice. [x | x <- [1..], odd x, mod x 7==0, mod x 9 == 3 ] works. I didnt know that there are "mod" function in haskell. my previous attempt was : [x | x<- [1..] , odd x, x / 2 == 0, (and here i had the main problems)].

Comment: @MNazar if you run into problems like you mentioned, why not include them? It makes a huge difference to see what you are struggling with, compared to asking a full fledged solution. I will be glad to help if i see something like your attempt plus the error ghc produces in a future question.